# TabBarController Smooth Slide

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have created a tab bar controller and I noticed that when I change tabs its an abrupt change-scene.  Is there a way to make it so that when a tab is changed it slides to that tab?

Comment: Check out the TabBarDemo from [VCTransitionsLibrary](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary). Whilst this isn't written in Swift, it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this is possible with a UITabBarController. If you want an animated change between the content, you will need to implement another structure. You could for example use a collectionview, where the cells hold your content-controllers views, and where you change to the other view per button-tap-action and call collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath()

Comment: This is possible with a `UITabBarController` - you need to make use of the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and `tabBarController(_:animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:toViewController:)`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, than this is the simplest way to do the animations.